# Variable dereferncing in makefiles

Tags: shell, makefile

Given a list of paths I want to separate out the directory part and the filename part of each of the element of the list inside a makefile. Something like following

```
MYLIST = \
        /home/folder1/folder2/fileName1 \
        /home/folder3/folder4/fileName2 \
        /home/folder5/folder6/fileName3 \
MYLIST:
    @for elems in $(MYLIST); \
    do \
        echo $(dir $$elems); \
        echo $(notdir $$elems); \
    done
```

But there is a problem with the variable dereferencing. I get the output as

```
 ./
 home/folder1/folder2/fileName1
 ./
 home/folder3/folder4/fileName2
 ./
 home/folder5/folder6/fileName3
```

whereas i want it to be

```
         /home/folder1/folder2/
         fileName1
         /home/folder3/folder4/
         fileName2
         /home/folder5/folder6/
         fileName3
```

Somehow $(@D) and $(@F) are not giving all the dir and fileName parts just the first one in the list.
Can somebody please tell how to get about this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because you're mixing two stages of expansion. Before invoking the shell to execute the rule all make variables and functions are expanded. So `$$elems` becomes `$elems` and this string is then used as the input for the `$(dir ...)` and `$(notdir ...)` functions. This string doesn't contain a `/`, so `dir` returns `./`, and `notdir` returns `$elems`. In the end, the following command is executed in the shell.

```
@for elems in /home/folder1/folder2/fileName1 /home/folder3/folder4/fileName2 /home/folder5/folder6/fileName3; \
do \
    echo ./; \
    echo $elems; \
done
```

William Pursell has given a possible workaround by using shell functions. Another possibility would be to perform the expansion before execution of the rule, like such:

```
MYLIST = \
        /home/folder1/folder2/fileName1 \
        /home/folder3/folder4/fileName2 \
        /home/folder5/folder6/fileName3 \

MYDIRS = $(dir $(MYLIST))
MYFILES = $(notdir $(MYLIST))

MYLIST:
        @for elems in $(MYDIRS) $(MYFILES); \
        do \
            echo $$elems; \
        done
```

`$(@D)` and `$(@F)` are not giving you all dir and fileName parts because they give the file and directory of the target of the current invokation of the rule. There is only one target at each moment. You may be able to use these automatic variables, however, to do what you want, by letting `make` do the looping, instead of the shell, like this:

```
MYLIST = \
        /home/folder1/folder2/fileName1 \
        /home/folder3/folder4/fileName2 \
        /home/folder5/folder6/fileName3 \

all: $(MYLIST)
$(MYLIST):
    @echo $(@D)
    @echo $(@F)
```

Comment: @Pein: As a point of style I would encourage you to write loops in make syntax whereever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had figured out the problem lies with the expansion stages. But was not able to work my way around.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the shell instead of make:

```
MYLIST = \
        /home/folder1/folder2/fileName1 \
        /home/folder3/folder4/fileName2 \
        /home/folder5/folder6/fileName3
MYLIST:
    for elems in $(MYLIST); \
    do \
    echo $$(dirname $$elems); \
    echo $$(basename $$elems); \
    done
```

Of course, at this point, the echo is redundant, and you could just as well do:

```
for elems in $(MYLIST); \
    do \
    dirname $$elems; \
    basename $$elems; \
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do that now...

```
MYLIST = \
    /home/folder1/folder2/fileName1 \
    /home/folder3/folder4/fileName2 \
    /home/folder5/folder6/fileName3

MYLIST:
    @$(foreach ELEMS,$(MYLIST), echo $(dir $(ELEMS)); echo $(notdir $(ELEMS));)
```

Don't know how i missed this before.